# Выбор интервала значений из csv файла в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

В [dataset.csv](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/123v/2N1xxkyTZ) 155 строк и 2 колонки, подскажите, как выбрать значения по индексу от 1-го до 77-го так чтобы не создавались ещё 5 колонок?

Мой код:

```
df = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", sep = ";", header = None)
df2 = df.loc[1:77]
x = df2[0].values
y = df2[1].values
df2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а откуда берутся остальные столбцы если их нет в CSV файле??

Comment: Забыл посмотреть в csv файл, там оказались 5 пустых колонок непонятно откуда. Вопрос закрыт

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Описанная в вопросе проблема не воспроизводится:

```
In [83]: df = pd.read_csv(Path.home() / "Downloads/dataset.csv", sep=";", header=None)

In [84]: df
Out[84]: 
         0     1
0    19.96  0.72
1    19.41  0.96
2    15.33  0.13
3    16.71  0.98
4    17.61  0.49
..     ...   ...
150  18.78  0.42
151  18.22  0.99
152  15.72  0.75
153  16.09  0.31
154  15.49  0.12

[155 rows x 2 columns]

In [85]: x = df.loc[:77, 0].to_numpy()

In [86]: y = df.loc[:77, 1].to_numpy()

In [87]: x
Out[87]: 
array([19.96, 19.41, 15.33, 16.71, 17.61, 15.15, 17.65, 16.69, 15.39,
       19.23, 16.89, 19.53, 16.28, 16.07, 16.3 , 19.05, 18.5 , 15.97,
       19.86, 15.44, 16.99, 19.62, 15.66, 17.58, 19.73, 15.  , 18.06,
       18.07, 17.12, 17.64, 16.88, 18.92, 17.25, 18.2 , 17.68, 19.17,
       17.86, 19.09, 16.21, 17.11, 19.11, 18.37, 18.16, 17.61, 15.62,
       18.6 , 18.35, 15.09, 16.59, 15.51, 18.26, 15.45, 16.45, 15.69,
       17.74, 18.97, 15.47, 16.49, 15.61, 18.1 , 15.87, 15.23, 18.75,
       18.4 , 16.53, 19.98, 19.18, 19.37, 17.75, 15.84, 16.5 , 17.99,
       17.75, 19.61, 16.95, 16.84, 18.13, 18.65])

In [88]: y
Out[88]: 
array([0.72, 0.96, 0.13, 0.98, 0.49, 0.98, 0.55, 0.13, 0.4 , 0.1 , 0.14,
       0.35, 0.44, 0.08, 0.97, 0.57, 0.79, 0.71, 0.51, 0.97, 0.56, 0.88,
       0.83, 0.02, 0.12, 0.87, 0.19, 0.19, 0.88, 0.68, 0.64, 0.4 , 0.9 ,
       0.5 , 0.62, 0.93, 0.15, 0.23, 0.9 , 0.33, 0.78, 0.59, 0.54, 0.12,
       0.7 , 0.64, 0.51, 0.28, 0.58, 0.62, 0.25, 0.03, 0.77, 0.67, 0.74,
       0.52, 0.62, 0.45, 0.49, 0.83, 0.62, 0.19, 0.49, 0.34, 0.55, 0.24,
       0.93, 0.46, 0.64, 0.7 , 0.2 , 0.92, 0.92, 0.14, 0.04, 0.37, 0.7 ,
       0.2 ])
```